# What's the best way to find the CMYK and RGB for flex banner design?

Tags: visualization

Please for flex banner design which colours are correct rgb or cmyk
i am confusing to make flex banner rgb neither cmyk
please give me suggestion aboutthis

Comment: Hi Vardhini, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you please give us a bit more information? I have no clue what you are trying to ask. Do you want to know what colours are on both RGB and CMYK? If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: **Ask the production house!**

Answer (score 0):

If you create digital design as website design, application design or any other format that will be used on electronic devices, you have to use RGB colours. For print as business cards, posters, billboards etc. - CMYK.

Comment: A "flex banner" is an exterior sales banner.. like those you see standing up with a curved wire in them...